# How to bind a timer to a progress ring with JS?

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I'm playing around with a progress ring, and I can't seem to get it to run on a timer. I am trying to make the progress ring propagate automatically and take, say, 0.5 seconds to go from 0% to whatever percent I set (65% in this case).

I used this progress ring as a base: http://llinares.github.io/ring-progress-bar/

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gTtGW/

I tried using a timer function, but I may not have been integrating that properly. In the fiddle, I have added:

```
for (var i = 0; i< 65; i++){
        range += i;
        setTimeout(timer,800);
    }
```

However, this breaks the progress ring. I thought that any time the range is updated (with the += i), the draw function would be called. What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not planning to use the `input[type=range]` element, you can change your code to this:

```
(function (window) {
'use strict';

var document = window.document,
    ring = document.getElementsByTagName('path')[0],
    range = 0,
    text = document.getElementsByTagName('text')[0],
    Math = window.Math,
    toRadians = Math.PI / 180,
    r = 100;

function draw() {
    // Update the wheel giving to it a value in degrees, getted from the percentage of the input value a.k.a. (value * 360) / 100
    var degrees = range * 3.5999,
        // Convert the degrees value to radians
        rad = degrees * toRadians,
        // Determine X and cut to 2 decimals
        x = (Math.sin(rad) * r).toFixed(2),
        // Determine Y and cut to 2 decimals
        y = -(Math.cos(rad) * r).toFixed(2),
        // The another half ring. Same as (deg > 180) ? 1 : 0
        lenghty = window.Number(degrees > 180),
        // Moveto + Arcto
        descriptions = ['M', 0, 0, 'v', -r, 'A', r, r, 1, lenghty, 1, x, y, 'z'];
    // Apply changes to the path
    ring.setAttribute('d', descriptions.join(' '));
    // Update the numeric display
    text.textContent = range;
    range++;
    if(range > 100) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

  // Translate the center axis to a half of total size
  ring.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + r + ', ' + r + ')');

 var timer = setInterval(draw,100);

}(this));
```

Basically changing `range` to a simple variable starting at 0, and increasing its value every time `draw()` is called. Creating an interval (named `timer`) to run every 0.1 seconds in this case (of course it's up to you), and clearing that interval from `draw()` when appropriate...

[**<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/yWbXA/14/)

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to update my fiddle where I had deleted the input. Would you know if the timer can be set on a cubic bezier as well?

Comment: @AtalayaCavallo You're welcome, and yes it should be possible as well, the timer and the function that makes the circle work together but are not correlated, so you could create something with a different figure/curve/whatever as long as you use the right math code...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
function inc() {
    var val = parseInt(range.value, 10)
    range.value = val + 1;
    draw(); // updating the value doesn't cause `onchange`.
    if (val < 100) { // don't go over 100
        setTimeout(inc, 100);
    }
}
inc();
```